# XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 error with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, console

I'm using this code in a Jquery mobile website.
However, it's return me an error with

```
 {readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"}
```

I stuck here and can't find out what is the problem !
and i didn't found a good answer.

```
$(function () {
    calldata();
});

function calldata() {
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/json.php" ;

var json = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': url,
        'error': function (data) { console.log(data); },
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return json;
})(); 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved =P

```
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'dataType': 'JSON', // this line was missing
        'url': url,
        'error': function (data) { console.log(data); },
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```