# XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 on IOS devices

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ios, ajax

I recently started getting the following message on a jquery ajax call only on IOS devices:

ERROR: NETWORK_ERR:
XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

The ajax call worked well for months on all devices but one of my clients started getting this message last week.

I have read some about it being a cross domain request problem but that should not be applicable in this case.

I have also read that changing async to true will fix the problem but I want to avoid that if I can.

Here is the ajax call:

the serverSideFunction parameter is in the form "AdvancedDistribution.aspx/SaveClicked"
where AdvancedDistribution.aspx is of course the aspx file and SaveClicked is the static WebMethod(C#).

para is just a 2d array with the parameter values.

```
function ajaxCall(serverSideFunction, para)
{
    ajaxReturn = "";  
    var dataPara = "{";
    for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++)
    {
    dataPara += "'" + para[i][0] + "':'" + para[i][1] + "'";
        if (i < para.length - 1)
        dataPara += ",";
    }
    dataPara += "}";

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serverSideFunction,
    data: dataPara,
    async: false,
    //&&JS01112013.2 Fix bug caused by IOS6 ajax caching
    headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"},
    beforeSend: function (xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg, status)
    {
        ajaxReturn = msg.d;
    },
    error: function (xhr, msg, e)
    {
        alert(e); //Error Callback
        alert('Ajax Callback Failed');
    }
    });

    return ajaxReturn;
}
```

Since this is still working on most devices I'm hoping that it will be as simple as just adding and IOS required header to the ajax call.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `async:true`

Comment: I believe async should be set false.. but I could be mistaken if this is `JSON` should you have something about `Global:false` somethere in your code..?

Comment: I believe from my research that setting async to true would fix the problem but I would like to retain the functionality as it is. I want the call to be synchronous.

Comment: there is a similar `SO` posting located here [Error 101](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025359/xmlhttprequest-exception-101-error-with-ajax/14025557#14025557) maybe this can shed some light

Comment: Anyone know why the async option should cause a network error?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE. In the SO post that you mentioned the fix was adding 'dataType': 'JSON' to the call. I have already done that... Unless it is case sensitive and dataType: "json" != dataType: "JSON". Does anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: you could always try it you know c# is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it... I just noticed your Global:false comment above.  Could you explain that?

Comment: One of my users has the same problem. He got it after upgrading to iOS7. I cannot reproduce it on my ipad.

Comment: I think the problem in my case was actually a timeout one :-p however ios reported it as "error 101". Also jquery 1.8.3 timeout setting does not seem to work for some reason.